# Problems Initializing Structures

Tags: c, struct, static, structure

Here are (some of) the structures that I am using; they are in a `.h` file:

```
struct rss_s {
    Radio_types device_type;    // Its device_type which is defined by the typedef above Radio_Types
    char * device_info;      // some thing about the radio NAV/COM/etc.
    char * device_model;     // the Manufactures part/model number.
    char * device_serial;    // the device's serial number..
    int power_48v;           // power to the unit..
    int power_400hz;
    int panel_lamps;         // turn off or on the Panel Lamps only
    void * radio_info;
};

typedef struct tuner_s {    // when we talk about 'sub-radios' we are really saying how many tuners are there??
    char * device_name;    // OS-name
    int frequency[tuned];
    int power;
    int dial_lamp;
    int fd[ ];      // file descriptors
}tuner;

//// 614L8 ::= C614L8

typedef enum Lp_Sw_614L8 { OFF_loop, LEFT, RIGHT, SLEW_LEFT, SLEW_RIGHT } loopsw_614L8;
typedef enum Mo_Sw_614L8 { OFF_614L8, ADF, ANT, LOOP } modesw_614L8;

struct radio_s_614L8 {
    loopsw_614L8 loop_sw_614L8;
    modesw_614L8 mode_sw_614l8;
    int sw_band;
    int sw_bfo;
    int meter;
    tuner * Tuner;
    int tuners;
};
```

Now file `main.c`, which has all of the normal includes:

```
// Radio 614L8<br>

static struct radio_s_614L8 radio_614L8 = { { .Tuner = tuner_614L8, .tuners = DIM( tuner_C_614L8 ) } };
static tuner tuner_614L8 = { { .device_name = "/dev/TBD", }  };

static struct rss_s radios[] = {
    { C614L8, "ADF", "614L8", "8384", & radio_C_614L8,},};

// now comes the normal main()
```

The errors that I have:

error: field name not in record or union initializer

error: (near    initialization for ‘radio_614L8.loop_sw_614L8’)

error:    ‘tuner_614L8’ undeclared here (not in a function)

error: field name    not in record or union initializer

error: (near initialization for    ‘radio_614L8.loop_sw_614L8’)

error: ‘tuner_C_614L8’ undeclared here    (not in a function)

error: field name not in record or union    initializer

error: (near initialization for‘tuner_614L8.device_name’)

error: ‘radio_C_614L8’ undeclared here    (not in a function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have:

```
static struct radio_s_614L8 radio_614L8 = { { .Tuner = tuner_614L8, .tuners = DIM( tuner_C_614L8 ) } };
static tuner tuner_614L8 = { { .device_name = "/dev/TBD", }  };
```

You need:

```
static tuner tuner_614L8 =  { .device_name = "/dev/TBD", };
static struct radio_s_614L8 radio_614L8 = { .Tuner = &tuner_614L8, .tuners = 1 };
```

You can't refer to a variable like `tuner_614L8` until you've defined or declared it.  You shouldn't try to make a non-array into an array, either.  You do need to take the address of the tuner, too.  You don't show `DIM`, but I'm assuming it is more or less one of these two equivalent macros:

```
#define DIM(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))
#define DIM(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))
```

---

On further analysis, your `tuner` structure contains a flexible array member.  You can't sensibly allocate such variables as static or global variables, or as automatic variables; you have to allocate them with `malloc()` and relatives to get a non-empty array.

However, with that caveat in mind, this code compiles:

```
typedef enum Radio_types { C614L8 } Radio_types;
enum { tuned = 5 };

typedef struct tuner_s
{
    char *device_name;
    int frequency[tuned];
    int power;
    int dial_lamp;
    int fd[];
} tuner;

typedef enum Lp_Sw_614L8 { OFF_loop, LEFT, RIGHT, SLEW_LEFT, SLEW_RIGHT } loopsw_614L8;
typedef enum Mo_Sw_614L8 { OFF_614L8, ADF, ANT, LOOP } modesw_614L8;

struct radio_s_614L8
{
    loopsw_614L8 loop_sw_614L8;
    modesw_614L8 mode_sw_614l8;
    int sw_band;
    int sw_bfo;
    int meter;
    tuner *Tuner;
    int tuners;
};

static tuner tuner_614L8 = { .device_name = "/dev/TBD", };
static struct radio_s_614L8 radio_614L8 = { .Tuner = &tuner_614L8, .tuners = 1 };

struct rss_s
{
    Radio_types device_type;
    char *device_info;
    char *device_model;
    char *device_serial;
    int power_48v;
    int power_400hz;
    int panel_lamps;
    void *radio_info;
};

struct rss_s radios[] =
{
    { C614L8, "ADF", "614L8", "8384", 0, 0, 0, &radio_614L8, },
};
```

Comment: ok i now have flipped it.. like you suggested... and the DIM is<br>#define DIM( a ) ( sizeof( a )/sizeof( a[0] ))
but I still have errors :(

Comment: Yup; see the update with compilable code.  For the intended uses (where the argument, `a`, is an array name), your definition of `DIM` is fine.  The paranoid would use parentheses around `a` in `sizeof((a)[0])`, which breaks differently when abused.

Comment: static tuner tuner_614L8 = { { .device_name = "/dev/TBD", }  };
 static struct radio_s_614L8 radio_614L8 = { { .Tuner = tuner_614L8, .tuners = DIM( tuner_614L8 ) } }; Still throughs lots of errors

Comment: Note that `{{ … }}` is wrong for a single structure; it is needed only in an array.  That was fixed twice.  And you can't apply `DIM` to a non-array. Copy my code verbatim to `x394.c` and compile it: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c x394.c`.

Comment: hang on Im putting my code up on my website(it works now typo :(.... http://www.phoenixaerospace.us/tmp/NexGen

Comment: Please review how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — same idea, two explanations.  My code qualifies, just about, as an MCVE, with the exception that it compiles.  There are currently two files (`main.c` and `rss.h`) on the web site.  But the main code references headers that are not there: `power.h`, `main.h`, `rss_init.h`.  I shouldn't have to try to work out whether they're necessary.

Comment: When I comment out the missing headers, and change: `static tuner tuner_614L8 = { { .device_name = "/dev/TBD", } }; static struct radio_s_614L8 radio_614L8 = { { .Tuner = & tuner_614L8, .tuners = 1 } };` to `static tuner tuner_614L8 = { .device_name = "/dev/TBD", }; static struct radio_s_614L8 radio_614L8 = { .Tuner = & tuner_614L8, .tuners = 1 };` (replacing `{{ … }}` with `{ … }` twice, as already mentioned, then `main.c` compiles OK.

Comment: ok thanks I found a few errors. I have reloaded the website w/ current files. I have all of the errors out now, and now i just have warnings: looks like my problem now  are "initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"

Comment: Don't put `&array` where you want just `array`.  Don't put `simple` where you mean `&simple`.  And note that in C, `int power_buss_48v();` is a function declaration but not a prototype function declaration.  You need `int power_buss_48v(void);` to declare a function that takes no arguments in C.